# play framework 1.4 - How to intercept static method call and redirec to another

Tags: java, interceptor, playframework-1.x

i want **intercept** (and not override) a controller `static` method call and (if a flag is true..) redirect to another method in another controller.

I need to redefine a method if a config flag is true without override.

```
public class Utils extends Controller {
    private static String pippo() {
        return "1";
    }
}

public class Another extends Controler {
    private static String pippo() {
        return "2";
    }
}

System.out.println(Utils.pippo());
out: 2
```

Comment: Are these supposed to be action methods? as in `public static void`?

Comment: no...is redirect function inside Controller Class... i want to intercept all redirect call because i want overwrite the static function (i want to append extra param in all internal redirect call) ... an interceptor pattern

Comment: Could you use one of the play interceptors like `@Before` https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/controllers#interceptions

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i found is:

```
public class MyController extends InterceptController {
    protected static void redirect(String url) {
        // default redirect impl.
        ...
    }
} 

public class InterceptController extends Controller {

    // re-write static method
    protected static void redirect(String url) {
        if (isActive()) {
            new RedirectWID(url).invoke(); // new impl. if flag is true
        } else {
            Controller.redirect(url);  // old impl. if flag = false
        }
    }
    ...
}
```